# How to calculate a function's derivative wrt a matrix argument?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

I have a function like this: $g(A)=c_1^\top F(A)c_2$, where $c_1,c_2\in\mathbb{R}^{d},A\in\mathbb{R}^{d\times d},F:\mathbb{R}^{d\times d}\to\mathbb{R}^{d\times d}$, and I'm looking for $\nabla_A g(A)$. The output of function g should be a number, therefore the derivative should be a matrix as well, but I'm not sure how to approach this. The function f, although having matrix input and output, operates element-wise and therefore the outputs only depend on the same indexed element in the input.

$F$ is a clipping function that clips the elements of $A$ to 1 if larger than 1, clips the elements to 0 if smaller than 0, and do nothing otherwise.

Edit: I had a guess after browsing several other similar questions: $c_1c_2^\top [\mathbb{1}(A_{m,n}\in[0,1])]_{m,n}$, but I'm not quite sure. The first thing I'm not sure about is whether the derivative of $F$ should follow at the end or should it be squeezed between $c_1,c_2$. The second part I'm not sure about is whether I can write the derivative this way.

Comment: Note that there are [two competing conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus#Layout_conventions) for the form of the matrix derivative. You should decide whether you want a numerator layout or denominator layout derivative.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by $f$ operating element-wise? Is the same function applied to all entries of the matrix?

Comment: How is $F$ defined?